# Order of ChangeTracker.Entries is different after SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I found the strange behaviour in ChangeTracker Entries. Basically I have simple Entity that contains list of Tags. When I create Entity with list of tags, in ChangeTracker I see list of entries in that order:

1. Entity

   1. Tag1
   2. Tag2
   3. Tag3

And this scenario is fine. I implemented interceptor that updates timestamps for each entity, so with that approach I have possibility to preserve order of tags.

But the problem is, when I use SaveChangesAsync multiple times, let's check that scenario:

1. Create Entity with list of tags
2. SaveChangesAsync
3. Interceptor is triggered, ChangeTracker.Entries return list of entities added or edited in proper order so timestamps are updated properly

   1. Entity
   2. Tag1
   3. Tag2
   4. Tag3
4. I create second Entity with list of tags (the same as previous one)
5. SaveChangesAsync
6. Interceptor is triggered, but ChangeTracker.Entries return list of entities added or edited in different order:

   1. Tag3
   2. Tag2
   3. Tag1
   4. Entity
7. So Interceptor sets timestamps, but order of tags is different so when I order them by timestamp, I have different order than I saved them

What can be a problem with ChangeTracker that changes order of entries after SaveChangesAsync is called?

I tried to debug EF, but I only found that something happens in IEntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraphAsync that mixes order.

Comment: `ChangeTracker.Entries` does not claim to provide entities in any particular order so you should not rely on it. _"What can be a problem with ChangeTracker"_ - I would argue that there is no problem with `ChangeTracker` you just using it in the way it was not supposed to.

Comment: Ok I agree that there is no problem with ChangeTracker, but on the other hand it's confusing that sometimes ChangeTracker.Entries() returns entities sorted in one way, sometime in another. I was not aware of it until now.

Comment: It can be a bit, but without [mre] it is hard to tell. And again - the change tracking implementation is an (obviously) implementation detail, including the order and how the tracked entities are stored and you should not rely on it in any way.